# How to add textviev if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

You can add a TextView to another without having to repeat everything?

```
if (Turni.equals("M"))
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            mHolder.txt_id.setTextColor(Color.RED);

else if (Turni.equals("F"))
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

                    mHolder.txt_id.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: In your actual code, you need the `{ }`, otherwise only the first lines will be handled.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by adding a TextView to another?
what you wrote is valid but use {} like Fllo said

Comment: Ok, but how can I put {}

Comment: [A little search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) should give you an answer.

Comment: Ok, perfect, I did not know that link, solved thanks

Comment: This is not a question and it is completely useless to the community. Consider deleting it with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
String Turni = turnoName.get(pos);
        if (Turni != null) 
        if (Turni.equals("M")){
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            mHolder.txt_ore.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else 
        if (Turni.equals("F")){
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mHolder.txt_ore.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else
            mHolder.txt_turno.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```